# How can I get the text between tags using python SAX parser?

Tags: python, xml, sax

What I need is just get the text of the corresponding tag and persist it into database. Since the xml file is big (4.5GB) I'm using sax. I used the *characters* method to get the text and put it in a dictionary. However when I'm printing the text at the *endElement* method I'm getting a new line instead of the text.

Here is my code:

```
def characters(self,content):
   text = unescape(content))
   self.map[self.tag]=text

def startElement(self, name, attrs):
   self.tag = name

def endElement (self, name)
   if (name=="sometag")
   print self.map[name]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The text in the tag is chunked by the SAX processor. `characters` might be called multiple times.

You need to do something like:

```
def startElement(self, name, attrs):
    self.map[name] = ''
    self.tag = name

def characters(self, content):
    self.map[self.tag] += content

def endElement(self, name):
    print self.map[name]
```

Comment: Thanks ! 
The below code is an accident or it should be like that ?
self.map[name] == ''

Comment: Where can I find reference to this behavior ?
The text in the tag is chuncked by the SAX processor. characters  might be called multiple times.

Comment: The behaviour is described in the docs: http://localhost/doc/python2.6-doc/html/library/xml.sax.handler.html#xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler.characters

Comment: Guess my local copy won't be very helpful...  http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.handler.html#xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler.characters

Comment: From the [SAX handler documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.handler.html#xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler.characters): “The Parser will call this method to report *each chunk* of character data.”